# Route not defined in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have defined a route in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard/create-sub-project/{id}', 'SubProjectController@create')->name('sub-project.create')->middleware('auth');
```

and adding it a view.php

```
<a href='{{ route('sub-project.create', $project->id) }}'>Create new project</a>
```

but it keeps on throwing an error

> Route [sub-project.create] not defined. (View:
>   view.blade.php)

Other routes I have defined works fine.

Comment: Does it show up if you run `php artisan route:list`? If not, do you have route cache enabled? You can clear that with `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment you should try running `php artisan route:clear`. If it doesn't help look at `php artisan route:list` because you might have some route grouping and this route might be prefixed with some other name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
php artisan route:list
```

The problem was, I have added two routes on the same name with the different intention that caused the issue. Removed duplicate fixed the issue in **Web.php**

Comment: For future if it helps you can run `php artisan route:list` from the terminal to get a list of all available routes and which Controllers/Methods they call to.

Answer (score 1):

In Your command prompt run

```
php artisan route:list
```

the Clear route cache by running

```
php artisan route:clear
```

then you will be good to go.